# Почему закрывается всё приложение?

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть основное окно в котором считаются точки, а потом выводятся графики. Почему у меня закрывается вся программа, когда закрываешь окно с графиками, если я выношу выведение графиков по нажатию на кнопку?

```
...
    QList<QPointF> XconstSeriesZero;
    QList<QPointF> XconstSeriesOne;
    QList<QPointF> XconstSeriesTwo;
    QList<QPointF> XconstSeriesThree;
    QList<QPointF> XconstSeriesFour;
...

... 
void ksp_ecology_dock::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    //![1]
    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->setTitle(QString("X=%1 м").arg(X, 0, 'f', 2));
    //![1]

    //![2]
    QValueAxis *axisX = new QValueAxis;
    axisX->setTitleText("t, час.");
    axisX->setTitleBrush(Qt::gray); // Цвет названия
    axisX->setLabelsColor(Qt::black); // Цвет элементов оси
    chart->addAxis(axisX, Qt::AlignBottom);
    //![2]

    //![3]
    QValueAxis *axisY = new QValueAxis;
    axisY->setTitleText("F(t)");
    chart->addAxis(axisY, Qt::AlignLeft);
    axisY->setTitleBrush(Qt::gray); // Цвет названия
    axisY->setLabelsColor(Qt::black); // Цвет элементов оси
    //![3]

    //![4]
    QLineSeries *diagramaXconstSeriesZero = new QLineSeries;
    diagramaXconstSeriesZero->append(XconstSeriesZero);
    chart->addSeries(diagramaXconstSeriesZero);
    diagramaXconstSeriesZero->attachAxis(axisX);
    diagramaXconstSeriesZero->attachAxis(axisY);
    //![4]

    //![5]
    QLineSeries *diagramaXconstSeriesOne = new QLineSeries;
    diagramaXconstSeriesOne->append(XconstSeriesOne);
    chart->addSeries(diagramaXconstSeriesOne);
    diagramaXconstSeriesOne->attachAxis(axisX);
    diagramaXconstSeriesOne->attachAxis(axisY);
    //![5]

    //![6]
    QLineSeries *diagramaXconstSeriesTwo = new QLineSeries;
    diagramaXconstSeriesTwo->append(XconstSeriesTwo);
    chart->addSeries(diagramaXconstSeriesTwo);
    diagramaXconstSeriesTwo->attachAxis(axisX);
    diagramaXconstSeriesTwo->attachAxis(axisY);
    //![6]

    //![7]
    QLineSeries *diagramaXconstSeriesThree = new QLineSeries;
    diagramaXconstSeriesThree->append(XconstSeriesThree);
    chart->addSeries(diagramaXconstSeriesThree);
    diagramaXconstSeriesThree->attachAxis(axisX);
    diagramaXconstSeriesThree->attachAxis(axisY);
    //![7]

    //![8]
    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    //![8]

    //![9]
    QMainWindow* window = new QMainWindow();
    window->setCentralWidget(chartView);
    window->resize(1200, 900);
    window->show();
    //![9]
} 
...
```

Comment: Что возвращает `окно_с_графиками->testAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose)`? Если `true`, то вам надо снимать этот флаг: `окно_с_графиками->setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose, false);`, либо искать, где вы его сами ставите.

Comment: @Arhad это ответ. Спасибо большое . Теперь не закрывается полностью программа.

Comment: Тогда выставите этот флаг главному окну (`главное_окно->setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose, true);`).